# How do I make a custom vertical axis?

Tags: c#

How do I make a custom vertical axis?

I'm making a game in C# and I have no idea how to make this idea work.
I want to there to be a invisible vertical line in the middle of the screen that mirrors specific things to the other side. I was thinking that it work in a way like this:
The new axis would be STH in this example, Left is negative numbers and right is positive.

```
let STHaxis = SetX(GetCenterX);
//I have no idea how to define this
let oppSTH = GetPlayerSTH;
//True Items
CreatePlayerShot01(GetPlayerSTH(), GetPlayerY(), 15, 270, 1.5, 3, 1);
//Mirrored Items                              ↓‎Ignore these numbers.↑
CreatePlayerShot01(oppSTH * -1, GetPlayerY(), 15, 270, 1.5, 3, 1);
```

But I need something that would make the STH axis exist...
Any ideas to have a mirror, even if it doesn't involve using this code at all. Thanks for reading this, I know I write a lot.

I could work with just moving the Y axis to the middle of my X axis.

Comment: Conceptually, are you hoping to hide the implementation details of mirrored coordinates?  Do you want to just end up with two different coordinate systems... either "normal" or "mirrored"?

Comment: I would like to have a copy of the Y axis or the ability to move it to the center of the screen by (GetCenterX), I also want it to have positive and negative numbers for ether side of the Axis, similar to the four quadrants system but only with the first and second quadrants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    let PX = GetPlayerX; //Gets your X
    let MX = GetClipMaxX; // Gets the max X can be (complete right)
    let MMX = GetClipMinX; // Gets the min X can be (complete left)
    let agr = MMX + PX; // Agr = PX in this case
    let mir = MX - PX; // Takes distance from minX and subtracts it from maxX
```